# UX Parameters for Interaction Design

Tags: gui-design, web

In a web or screen-based GUI, when a user performs an interaction, or there is a state change triggered by another user or server processing, what are the parameters you can change given a specific UI element to denote that it is changed?

For example, a UI element such as a button state can have an "inactive" or "active" state.

What parameters are available, and what are the weighting on effectiveness and response time?

I've heard it cited as:

- Position
- Size
- Rotation
- Color

I think there are two more, and I'm not sure what weighting each one have or if it is a weighting or just an ordered list.

I'm not looking for a specific UI design, rather the psychological theory behind some UI designs. Having some Google-Fu problems.

Comment: Did you ever find the other two you were looking for?

Comment: No. I guess I'll email the professor I learned it from? Maybe just flag for deletion and wipe it from my memory.

Comment: Well now you have us curious! Email the prof! :)

Comment: I got a response, she said I may have been remembering Bertin's Visual Variables. Her reference was in Designing Visual Interfaces by Mullet & Sano (1994).

Here's one wiki article I found: http://www.infovis-wiki.net/index.php?title=Visual_Variables

Comment: Should I answer my own question with the information I found, or have a moderator close it?

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged if you feel it is good information. Go for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding information I found that I originally posted in a comment.

I was thinking of [Bertin's Visual Variables](http://www.infovis-wiki.net/index.php?title=Visual_Variables), which seems to originated from the French book, Jaques Bertin's *Sémiologie graphique*, referenced in reference was in *Designing Visual Interfaces* by Mullet & Sano (1994).

They are:

- Position
- Size
- Shape
- Value
- Colour
- Orientation
- Texture

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones you list:

- Position
- Size
- Rotation
- Color

You could list many, many more:

- typeface
- type/icon weight
- brightness
- contrast
- pattern
- animation
- opacity
- shadow/border
- etc

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for. 

The design patterns I am looking for were based of a psychological study, and they were weighted and not necessarily tied to context-dependent items, such as text and animation.

This helps, but I am going to need citations if I use this.

Comment: I remember it being described to me like Hicks, Millers, or Fitt's law were described to me.

Comment: @JordanMcGuigan Hmm...sorry, I'm not much help there. Sounds like a list some UX speaker put together.

Comment: @JordanMcGuigan those aren't parameters used to differentiate UI elements.  They are heuristics used for interaction design which have only a very loose connection to differentiating elements.  If you are looking for something along the lines of hicks/millers/fitts you should rephrase the question.

Comment: That might be why I'm having Google-Fu issues. I'll update it.